# Contacts android application development

Tags: java, android-contacts, android

I wrote Adding contacts Android App which contains one name field and one number field and a save button,when enter name and number and press the save button it will add that contact to contact list..It working fine..but when your not entered anything and pressed save button it saving the contact with "noname"..for this i wrote if and else condition but it is not working..please give me solution
    this is my source code:

```
 package com.example.contacts;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentProviderOperation;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    //import android.view.Menu;

    public class ContactDetails extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_details);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_details, menu);
            return true;
        }
        public void onSave(View view)
        {
            EditText mytext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String name=mytext.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(this,name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            EditText mytext1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            String number=mytext1.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(this,number,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ops = new ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ();

             ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
             ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                 .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                 .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                 .build());
                 if (name != "") {
                 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
                 ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                     .withValue(
                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                 name).build());
             }
                 else
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Valid Name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     return;
                 }


             if (number != null) {
                 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
                 newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number)
                     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                     .build());
             }
             else
             {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Valid Number",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 return;
        }                 
             try {
                 getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Contact Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        }
        public void onCancel(View v)
        {`enter code here`
            EditText et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            et1.setText("");
            EditText et2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            et2.setText("");
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use checking string  like this

```
if ((!name.equals("")) && name !=null ) {
                 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
                 ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                     .withValue(
                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                 name).build());
             }
                 else
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Valid Name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     return;
                 }


             if (!(number.equals("")) && number !=null) {
                 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
                 newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number)
                     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                     .build());
             }
             else
             {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Valid Number",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 return;
        }
```

Comment: if ((!name.equals("")) && name !=null )...it is not working..if you used name.isEmpty() it will work